# How to group rows so as to use value_counts on the created groups with pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have some customer data such as this in a data frame:

```
S No Country Sex
1    Spain   M
2    Norway  F
3    Mexico  M
...
```

I want to have an output such as this:

```
Spain
M = 1207
F = 230

Norway 
M = 33
F = 102

...
```

I have a basic notion that I want to group my rows based on their countries with something like `df.groupby(df.Country)`, and on the selected rows, I need to run something like `df.Sex.value_counts()`

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think need [`crosstab`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.crosstab.html):

```
df = pd.crosstab(df.Sex, df.Country)
```

Or if want use your solution add [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html) for columns with first level of `MultiIndex`:

```
df = df.groupby(df.Country).Sex.value_counts().unstack(level=0, fill_value=0)
print (df)
Country  Mexico  Norway  Spain
Sex                           
F             0       1      0
M             1       0      1
```

EDIT:

If want add more columns then is possible set which level parameter is converted to columns:

```
df1 = df.groupby([df.No, df.Country]).Sex.value_counts().unstack(level=0, fill_value=0).reset_index()
print (df1)
No Country Sex  1  2  3
0   Mexico   M  0  0  1
1   Norway   F  0  1  0
2    Spain   M  1  0  0

df2 = df.groupby([df.No, df.Country]).Sex.value_counts().unstack(level=1, fill_value=0).reset_index()
print (df2)
Country  No Sex  Mexico  Norway  Spain
0         1   M       0       0      1
1         2   F       0       1      0
2         3   M       1       0      0

df2 = df.groupby([df.No, df.Country]).Sex.value_counts().unstack(level=2, fill_value=0).reset_index()
print (df2)
Sex  No Country  F  M
0     1   Spain  0  1
1     2  Norway  1  0
2     3  Mexico  0  1
```

Comment: Looks very neat! Thanks! What does `unstack` do?

Comment: @unstack reshape `MultiIndex` Series to `DataFrame`

Comment: Without the `unstack` , the output is `Spain       M      602
        F      509
        O        1` and so on. I was thinking that if I put one more `groupby` say `groupby(df.Continent)` before the `country`, there will be three levels of grouping. Will `unstack` work then?

Comment: @Vibhu - Yes, it return MultiIndex Series

Comment: @Vibhu - give me a sec

Comment: @Vibhu - Check eited answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [`pandas.pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html):

```
res = df.pivot_table(index='Country', columns='Sex', aggfunc='count', fill_value=0)

print(res)

        SNo   
Sex       F  M
Country       
Mexico    0  1
Norway    1  0
Spain     0  1
```