# Converting Groupby Object into DataFrame objects in a loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe `df` that looks like this

```
No Country Sex Age Group
1    Spain   M Young
2    Norway  F Middle
3    Mexico  M Elderly
...
```

My aim is to group this data based on country first, then do analysis based on sex and age groups, using `.value_counts()`

Thus, I used `groupby` on this via `df2 = df.groupby(df.Country)`and looped like this

```
for d in df2:
    print(type(d))
```

I am getting this output:

```
<class 'tuple'>
<class 'tuple'>
<class 'tuple'>
...
```

I wanted to use

```
for d in df2:
    print(pd.DataFrame(d).Sex.value_counts())
```

but I am getting this error

```
DataFrame constructor not properly called!
```

I had asked a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51058073/how-to-group-rows-so-as-to-use-value-counts-on-the-created-groups-with-pandas/51058114?noredirect=1#51058114) yesterday, but that was limited to a very particular query. What I want to learn is to know how to "group" layers into chunks and then do analysis on those particular chunks.

Thanks!

Comment: the reason you get `<class 'tuple'>` is because `.groupby()` returns a tuple of size 2, where the first element is your grouping (i.e. the country) and the second is the data for that group, which is already a dataframe.

Comment: Thanks @asongtoruin !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think better is use:

```
s = df.groupby('Country').Sex.value_counts()
print (s)
Country  Sex
Mexico   M      1
Norway   F      1
Spain    M      1
Name: Sex, dtype: int64
```

But if want use loops is necessary unpack tuples name of group and df by adding another variable `i`:

```
df2 = df.groupby(df.Country)
for i, d in df2:
    print(type(d))
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
```

Or use [`GroupBy.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html):

```
def func(x):
    print (x)
    a = x.Sex.value_counts()
    #another code 
    return a

df2 = df.groupby(df.Country).apply(func)
```

Comment: Thanks! `Groupby.apply` is most useful to me!

Comment: @Vibhu - Yes, it is obviously nice use, but there is one gotcha, see [Warning](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#flexible-apply)